# Use boto3 to download from public bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to list files from a public bucket on AWS but the best I got was list my own bucket and my own files. I'm assuming that boto3 is using my credentials configured in the system to list my things.

How can I force it to list from a specific bucket, rather than my own bucket?

```
#http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/
g_bucket = "sentinel-s2-l1c"
g_zone = "eu-central-1"
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass the `region_name` when creating the client

```
s3client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1')
```

Then list objects from the bucket

```
objects = s3client.list_objects(Bucket='sentinel-s2-l1c')
```

Comment: Someone better give you a medal! Thank you very much

Comment: You saved my day +1