# How to generate URL to download file from S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to obtain URLs pointing to cloud-optimized geoTIFFs from Amazon's [Copernicus Digital Elevation Model](https://registry.opendata.aws/copernicus-dem/) bucket.

After installing `boto3` (with `pip3 install boto3`), I do, relying on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34866092/8565438) to the question [Can I use boto3 anonymously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865927/can-i-use-boto3-anonymously/34866092#34866092) to download a single file:

```
import boto3
from botocore import UNSIGNED
from botocore.client import Config

s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='eu-central-1', config=Config(signature_version=UNSIGNED))
```

Then I query for list of objects in the bucket, using the second line of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42091396/8565438) to the question [Use boto3 to download from public bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42090830/use-boto3-to-download-from-public-bucket):

```
objects = s3.list_objects(Bucket='copernicus-dem-30m')
```

I then access to a value in `objects['Contents']`, the first one, for example (ie index `0`):

```
key = objects['Contents'][0]['Key']
```

`key` is now:

```
Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N00_00_E006_00_DEM/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N00_00_E006_00_DEM.tif
```

I download this file by doing:

```
s3.download_file('copernicus-dem-30m', key, key.split('/')[-1])
```

**Instead of downloading, how can I generate a URL, which later I can use to download the file, maybe using `wget` or just pasting it to a browswer?**

---

<sub>This code shown above is based on the thread: [How to get Copernicus DEM GeoTIFFs for a bounding box using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412437/how-to-get-copernicus-dem-geotiffs-for-a-bounding-box-using-python).</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See Geoffrey’s answer for the format of the S3 URLs for public access buckets.

To generate a URL that works regardless of whether the bucket/object is public, you can use [`generate_presigned_url`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html):

```
s3.generate_presigned_url(
    'get_object',
    Params = {'Bucket': 'copernicus-dem-30m', 'Key': key},
    ExpiresIn = SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT
)
```

… with a suitably chosen `SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT`  (in seconds).

Comment: Thank you. I get the error: AttributeError: 'S3' object has no attribute 'client'

Comment: Looking it up...

Comment: @zabop Sorry, copy&paste error. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks @Konrad, works now! :) I realized that the url generated does not in fact depend on SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT, and I get the same URL if I don't pass any SIGNED_URL_TIMEOUT value. Can accept in 2 mins...

Comment: @zabop Ah, yes, I hadn’t paid attention to your specific use-case: your bucket is public so you technically don’t need a pre-signed URL at all. My answer is more general and will also work for private buckets.

Answer (score 4):

S3 uses this format:
https://<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com/<key>

```
url = 'https://copernicus-dem-30m.s3.amazonaws.com/' + key
```

So the example above will look like this:
https://copernicus-dem-30m.s3.amazonaws.com/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N00_00_E006_00_DEM/Copernicus_DSM_COG_10_N00_00_E006_00_DEM.tif

Answer (score 0):

I had a secured view ad in that I did this:

```
@login_required
def product_download(request):
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id')
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=product_id)
    if ProductOrder.objects.filter(order__user=request.user, product=product_id).exists():
        pre_signed_url = generate_presigned_url(product.excel_file)
        if pre_signed_url is None:
            return HttpResponse("Unable to generate download link.", status=500)
        return JsonResponse({"url":pre_signed_url})
    return HttpResponse("Unable to locate your purchased of the file.", status=500)
```

and then generate_presigned_url method. I am giving static key currently but you can save key of your file in every product and pass it as generic.
solution above returns a url and opening that URL will automatically download the object.

```
import boto3
from django.conf import settings


def generate_presigned_url(file_key, expiration=60):
    """
    Generate a pre-signed URL for an Amazon S3 file.
    
    :param file_key: The key of the file in the S3 bucket
    :param expiration: Time in seconds for the pre-signed URL to remain valid
    :return: Pre-signed URL as string. If error, returns None.
    """
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                                region_name=settings.AWS_REGION_NAME,
                                aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                            )
    try:
        response = s3_client.generate_presigned_url('get_object',
                                                    Params={'Bucket': settings.AWS_STORAGE_PRODUCTS_BUCKET_NAME,
                                                            'Key': "EW_9-Box Talent-Grid Template-v1.0.xlsx"},
                                                    ExpiresIn=expiration)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error generating pre-signed URL: {e}")
        return None
    return response
```